# create a specific list from strings

Tags: python, string, loops

**Edited according to comments:**

I would like to use the strings `'ABC'` and `'123'` to create the list

```
['A1','B2','C3','A3','C1']
```

The logic would be to pair the first string with the second string in sequence and then again backwards:

forwards: A1, B2, C3
backwards: A3, B2, C1

`B2` only appears once as the final list should be distinct values.

I should be able to expand each of the two strings(they will always match in length) and have the same result pattern.

I tried a couple of things but I would like to know if there is a more pythonic way to accomplish this.

Comment: Which *two* lists? I see one.

Comment: What is the logic that leads to your output???

Comment: This explanation is insufficient to determine a solution: why and how `'B2'`is omitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solutions will work in Python 3.x,

```
from collections import OrderedDict

s1 ='ABC'
s2 = '123'

result = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(first + second for first, second in zip(s1 + s1, s2 + s2[::-1])))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'A3', 'C1']
```

This first solution assumes you only need to repeat the iterables once. If you have to repeat the shortest iterable more than once you could use [cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to iterate several times over it:

```
from itertools import cycle

s1 ='ABC'
s2 = '123'

seen = set()
result = []
for first, second in zip(cycle(s1), s2 + s2[::-1]):
    first_second = first + second
    if first_second not in seen:
        seen.add(first_second)
        result.append(first_second)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'A3', 'C1']
```

The idea in this second solution is to use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) of seen elements and only add to the final result if not seen. Finally you could combine the solutions and use `cycle` and [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from itertools import cycle
from collections import OrderedDict

s1 ='ABC'
s2 = '123'

result = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(first + second for first, second in zip(cycle(s1), s2 + s2[::-1])))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'A3', 'C1']
```

Answer (score 1):

If version greater than 3.6:

```
print(list(map(''.join,list(dict.fromkeys(list(zip(s1,s2))+list(zip(s1,s2[::-1])))))))
```

Output:

```
['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'A3', 'C1']
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried a couple of things but I would like to know if there is a more
>   pythonic way to accomplish this.

Without saying what you've tried, it's hard to suggest an alternative, pythonic or otherwise. Looking at what you're doing, it seems you're constructing a mapping between sets of the form:

[image: Set Mapping]

This is about as atomic as it gets with respect to logical relationships; I'm not sure there's any method that would be quicker than a dumb-as-a-rock string concatenation by index:

```
x = 'ABC'
y = '123'

new_list = [x[0] + y[0], x[1]+y[1], x[2]+y[2], x[0]+y[2], x[2]+y[0]]
```

Output:

```
['A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'A3', 'C1']
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. However, this is manual and would have to be edited if the strings change.